# Convert Func(Of Type, Boolean) to Expression(Of Func(Of Type, Boolean))?

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework, lambda, expression-trees

I've got the following code:

```
Dim query As IQueryable(Of someObject) = 
    New ObjectQuery(Of someObject)(queryString, db, MergeOption.NoTracking)
        .Where(CType(Function(x) x.Publish = True,
                     Expression(Of Func(Of someObject, Boolean))))
```

And it gives me an error that says:

> Cannot convert expression of type Func(someObject) System.Nullable(Of
>   Boolean) to type System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of
>   System.Func(someObject, Boolean)).

I have also tried:

```
 .Where(CType(Function(x) x.Publish = True,
                     Expression(Of Func(Of someObject, Nullable(Of Boolean)))))
```

which doesn't work either.

If I don't have the CType my `where` comes up with a narrowing conversion error from IQueryable and IEnumerable, so I need that there, but I am not sure how to write that where parameter as an expression to so it can be converted. Any help?

Comment: is Publish's type (x.Publish) a Nullable Boolean? If so you should just need to change the Expression to look something like this. Expression(Of Func(Of someObject, System.Nullable(Of Boolean)))...

Comment: @Brian Dishaw, no it isn't a nullable Boolean, and I tried what you suggested and it still said the same thing except the last Part says Nullable(Of Boolean) instead of just Boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use casting with `CType` here - create the expression directly:

```
Dim expr As Expression(Of Func(Of someObject, Nullable(Of Boolean))) =
    Function(x) x.Publish = True

Dim query As IQueryable(Of someObject) = 
    New ObjectQuery(Of someObject)(queryString, db, MergeOption.NoTracking)
        .Where(expr)
```

Expressions need to be created as such. It's not possible to convert existing `Func` into an expression.

Comment: @A. is there anyway to write that such that I can put everything inside the .Where without declaring an additional variable?

Comment: I'm not an VB.NET specialist, so I tried on my own and it works both in your version with `CType` and with inlined `expr`. So the problem must be in other place. Could you show your `someObject` definition?

Comment: @A. Yeah this worked for me, I just wanted to have it all into the .Where, when I try, what do your tools -> options -> projects and solutions -> vb default options look like? I get no runtime or compile errors with this code, (when I just write the function without the Ctype), but it still comes up as underlined and whatnot. The object isn't a problem, it's generated from db by Entity Framework.

Comment: Explicit On, Strict Off, Compare Binary, Infer On. .NET 4.0

Comment: @A. yeah that is what I have too. Ah well I will just use the multi-line solution, it still compiles and runs either way, I just wanted to get rid of that underline.